# Using OpenCv with CLion

Tags: c++, opencv, clion

Hey im trying to use the OpenCV Lib on elementary OS (based on Ubuntu).

I followed this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1K9rXiei9I

I added this lines to the CmakeList.txt:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(myOpenCVTest ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

But when i build the project it fails with some errors like:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_core
...
```

Can anyone help me???

Comment: do you have OpenCV installed on the default path?

Comment: hmm... its installed under home/Projects/opencv/opencv-3/build

Comment: under user/bin there is no folder called ld!

Comment: how did you install opencv?

Comment: ( you can either install it to the system path or set the path manually using -L<path_to_opencv> )

Comment: I installed it like in the video.  How can i set the path?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I solved the problem.

First I deleted all old OpenCV files and installations.

After that I followed this [guide](http://embedonix.com/articles/image-processing/installing-opencv-3-1-0-on-ubuntu/) to install OpenCV and all required packages.

And now everything is working with this CmakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(OpenCVTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Comment: In addition to guide, I needed to do `sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf'` and `sudo ldconfig`

Comment: more generally `target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )`

Comment: `${PROJECT_NAME}` should be in the answer, so people who copy it will copy something that will work :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to forcefully declare `OpenCV_FOUND 1` in the cmake file, The whole file looks like :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(testing)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(OpenCV_FOUND 1)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(testing ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(testing ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Answer (score 0):

(following our chat in the comments section)

I am not sure what video did you use for the installation, but assuming you used cmake based installation you usually run `make` followed by `sudo make install` that copies everything to the right location

Alternatively you can add `link_directories(home/Projects/opencv/opencv-3/build/lib/)`
and `include_directories((home/Projects/opencv/opencv-3/include/)` to your CMakeLists.txt